# How to trigger jQuery asual's address plugin's change event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-address

I'm using the jQuery Asual Address plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

jQuery Asual Address plugin is used like this

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});

$.address.change(changeFunction);
```

If I click twice on a link "index.php" then the URL doesn't change in the second time and Change event is not fired and hence the page doesn't reload. Any idea how can I trigger jquery address change?

Regards,
Sanket

Comment: You have an extra apostrophe (`'`) in your code - is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part with this excellent plugin is that the `$.address` is a regular object and not a jQuery one (the `$` is misleading here).

For the trigger to work, you need to use it this way (I've got this reading through the plugins source):

```
$($.address).trigger("change");
```

Unfortunately this leads to the drawback that you cannot rely on the usual caller parameters of `value`, `path`, `pathNames`, `parameterNames`, `parameters` and `queryString`. You need to build the callback function that way so it can extract those values internally (e.g. via the `$.address.value()` method).